# Assigning a message from a categorized contact to a different folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I have some contacts under a category and I would each message I receive from these contacts to be assigned to a designated folder.

How do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: And you would like to write something that does this in VBA?  Can you show us what code you have started with, and what specific problems you are having, as this site works much better in that way.

Comment: Yes. But I have no experience with writing vba code to Outlook (only Excel) and I see that there is very few material in the internet for that. So as of now I did nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules allow you to manage your received mail from specific senders into folders.

You can create a public group with all of the needed contacts within it and assign the public group to a specific folder.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/outlook-help/manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-HA010355682.aspx

Comment: I don't know of a way to achieve it only with the rules

Comment: @AmihaiZivan - what specifically can't you achieve with rules, it seems fairly easy according to these instructions.

Comment: @iandotkelly Sorry for the long delay. What I want to achieve is the following: I have a set of categorized contacts, and I want that every message that comes from a contact that is in that set will be automatically moved to a certain folder. I couldn't do it with rules.

Comment: @AmihaiZivan Could you not create a public group containing the contacts? You could then use rules to send to a certain folder.

Comment: @Gareth That would be a better solution to the problem, thanks.